# Are these two languages regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Let $\operatorname{value}(x)$ be the result when the symbols of $x$ are multiplied from left to right according to

$\qquad \displaystyle\begin{array}{c|ccc} 
    \times & a & b & c \\
    \hline 
    a & a & a & c \\
    b & c & a & b \\
    c & b & c & a
   \end{array}$

Is $L=\{xy \mid |x|=|y| \land \operatorname{value}(x) = \operatorname{value}(y)\}$ regular?

Is $L=\{xy \mid \operatorname{value}(x)= \operatorname{value}(y)\}$ regular?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I thing 1st one is regular where as second is non-regular.

Answer (score 6):

Hint for (1): consider a different type of value, $\mathrm{value}(s) = 1$ if $s$ ends with $z$, and $\mathrm{value}(s) = 0$ otherwise. Define the language $L$ as in your case, and consider $L \cap x^* z y^* z$.

Hint for (2): consider the language $L_\alpha = \{xy : \mathrm{value}(x) = \mathrm{value}(y) = \alpha \}$. What is the relation between $L_\alpha$ and $M_\alpha = \{ x : \mathrm{value}(x) = \alpha \}$? Is $M_\alpha$ regular?

Comment: Nice hints! (1) still needs hard work to find a good $xy$ that fails when the middle is 'shifted'. (2) I almost had the impression that two parts with the same evaluation was equivalent to the final evaluation $a$ because of the diagonal. Alas: the multiplication is not associative. (to avoid misunderstanding, this does not harm your solution).